# Time complexity of second nested loop is just half

Tags: java, time-complexity

I have the following code. The running time of the code as I see it is O(n^2) as it runs from `1, ..., n-1`, so their sum is O(n^2). I got that the running time is indeed (n-1)(n/2), so the inner loops runs from 1 to n/2, but as I see it, it runs from 1 to n-1. Can you please show why the inner loop runs at most (n/2) times?

```java
public static void method2(int[] array, int n)
{
  for (int index = 1; index <= n - 1; index++){
    privateMethod2(array[index], array, 0, index - 1);
  } // end method2
public static void privateMethod2(int entry, int[] array, int begin, int end)
{
  int index;
  for (index = end; (index >= begin) && (entry < array[index]); index--){
    array[index + 1] = array[index];
    array[index + 1] = entry;
} // end privateMethod2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worst case, the inner loop runs n/2 times on average. At first iteration it runs only one time from index 0 to index 0, on second iteration it runs 2 times from index=1 to index =0, and on the last iteration it runs n times. So on average it runs n/2 times

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, it's `sum(1+2+...+n) = n^2` and not `n/2` as I understand it? The question asked for worst case though and not average case although the answer as it seems is average case. How did you computed it on average please? Amortized analysis?

Comment: The inner loop on its worst case runs: (1+2+3+..+n) times and the outer loop runs n times. To compute complexity you should do n*(n/2) because in the worst case the inner loop runs n/2 times on average

Comment: Thank you but really still did not get it why inner loop in worst case runs in `n/2`

Comment: Because at first iteration it run 1 time, then 2 times, then 3 and at last iteration it runs n time in worst case. So in worst case it runs n/2 iteration on average.

Comment: As i see it that for each iteration of the outer loop, we will have at most n-1 in the inner loop, so obviously it's `n(n-1)`.  I am not able to grasp it alternatibely as you said. Thanks anyway

Comment: I see! Wow. It's very straightfoward! It's simply `1+2+3+...+n-1 = n(n-1)/2`! Is that correct please?